# AJAX & PHP -Retrieving more than one value

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'll get to the point, assume my PHP script returns an array with two values, how would I address them within javascript?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function ValidateCard(cardno)
{
if (cardno.length==0)
  { 
  document.getElementById("txtprice").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtprice").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","coding/validation/validatecard.php?cardno="+cardno,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

As you can see whatever is returned is send to display within a div tag, how would I differentiate between data?

Thanks

Comment: As an entirely separate suggestion, you should check out jQuery AJAX code for something like this, its a whole lot cleaner and there is lots of great documentation. http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: Okay I'll have a look, thanks :)

Comment: I would check out using JSON to return stuff. That means your PHP will output to JSON rather than HTML, but it is much more flexible if the result is being managed by Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use json to serialize it so that javascript can read it.

So, in php `json_encode($arr);`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Then in javascript.
you should be able to do something like jsarr[key] to get the values

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$result = array('success'=>1, 'messgae'=>"the message you want to show");
echo json_encode($result);
?>


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
     result = xmlhttp.responseText.evalJSON(true);
     //you can use result as array to get the information you want to check 
      if (result['success']) {
         document.getElementById("successs").innerHTML=result['message'];
       }
    }
  }
```

Comment: when posting code, make sure you use the code formatting button or ``. I fixed it for you, so someone just needs to verify it to update it.